# Angular How to check checkbox with click on div

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

I need to check/unchec checkbox with click on div "user check" and call doIfChecked(user).

I can check checkbox in ng-repeat and call doIfChecked.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('cont', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  
$scope.users = {user1:1,user2:2,user3:3};
  
$scope.toggleUserCo = function(user) {
    user.co = !user.co;
}


$scope.doIfChecked = function (array) {

}

}]);
```

```css
.user_check {
width: 600px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


        <div class="user_check" ng-app="app" ng-controller="cont" >
          
<div class="user_check" ng-app="app" ng-click="toggleUserCo()" ng-repeat="us in users">
    <input type="checkbox" checklist-value="contact" checklist-model="user.co" ng-click="doIfChecked(user)"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `user.co` is some boolean value and `checklist-model` is the equivalent to `ng-model` in whatever directive you're using, you can set the `ng-click` on the `div` to set `user.co = !user.co`

For example:

```
<div class="user_check" ng-app="app" ng-click="toggleUserCo()">
    <input type="checkbox" checklist-value="contact" checklist-model="user.co" ng-click="doIfChecked(user)"/>
</div>
```

And in your controller (or, based on the fact that I don't see you having a controller defined inside of the `ng-app`, I guess this would go wherever you're putting your logic (which should be a controller or service...)):

```
$scope.toggleUserCo = function() {
    $scope.user.co = !$scope.user.co;
}
```

**Edit**

Since this is in an `ng-repeat`, you can just pass the `user` object to the `toggleUserCo` function and perform the operation on that:

```
<div class="user_check" ng-app="app" ng-click="toggleUserCo(user)">
```

And

```
$scope.toggleUserCo = function(user) {
    user.co = !user.co;
}
```

Comment: thank you! but my block "user_check" in ng-repeat, and i have many blocks and checkboxes, sorry that forgot to wrote it.

Comment: i updated my code with your advice, but it not work.

Comment: See the markup in [this](http://jsbin.com/homemegeqe/1/edit) jsBin.  That should work.  You're still not passing the `user` to the `toggleUserCo` function